# How to read JSON data with Python

Tags: python, json

I'm new to python and created some code to read JSON data. Basically I want to read for each item, the consumption values and perform some calculations.

## 1 Data is coming from some websocket

```
     results = await websocket.recv()
```

## 2 Display structure of the

```
     loaded_json = json.loads(results)
     for json_item in loaded_json:
          print(json_item)
```

The JSON is formatted as next.

```
{
    '1558527178757-0': {
        'timestamp': '1558527179', 
        'consumption': '0.03604', 
        'generated': '0.7317073170731706'
    }
}
```

Basically I need to process all items and calculate the total consumption. So the question is how to Loop and access the value for "consumption".

Lots of different forums ans example code.

See above.

Comment: iterate on the values, not keys. Then access with `|'consumption']` on the dict values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
json_dict = {
      "1558527178757-0": {
        "timestamp": "1558527179",
        "consumption": "0.03604",
        "generated": "0.7317073170731706"
      }
    }

sum([float(v['consumption']) if v['consumption'] else 0 for k,v in json_dict.items() ])
0.03604 # Output
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
list_of_values_to_be_summed = []

for key in json_dict:
    string_consumption_value = json_dict[key]['consumption'] # access the value of 'consumption'
    consumption_value = float(string_consumption_value) # since you have a string, you need to convert it to a float)
    list_of_values_to_be_summed.append(consumption_value) # append it to a list

summed_consumption = sum(list_of_values_to_be_summed)
```